# How to access pipeline through GMainLoop?

Tags: gstreamer

I've got an application reading a movie file, and I would like to reset the stream to its initial position when it reaches the end of the stream.

So I've got the usual structure, I added a bus to watch the events

```
bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
gst_object_unref (bus);
```

And here is a snipet of the bus_call function

```
static gboolean bus_call (GstBus     *bus,
                      GstMessage *msg,
                      gpointer data)
{
    GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg))
    {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End of stream\n");
            g_main_loop_quit (loop);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

So for now when I reach the end of the stream I just quit the loop.
Can I access my pipeline throught the loop?
Thanks for reading, please let me know if I'm trying to do something impossible

ps: I want to avoid setting my pipeline as a global variable, or pass to bus_call a structure containing my pipeline and loop, because it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goal was to auto rewind when the end of the stream was reached. The user could then hit the play button, to play it again.

So I skirted the problem and modified the callback function of my play button. 
Now it detect the current stream position, and compare it to the length of the stream.

```
gint64 streamPosition, streamLength;
GstFormat format = GST_FORMAT_TIME;

gst_element_query_position (pipeline, &format, &streamPosition);
gst_element_query_duration (pipeline, &format, &streamLength);
if (streamPosition==streamLength)
    stopIt(widget,pipeline);
```

and if the current stream position equals the stream length, it means we are at the end of the stream. and so I call a function to rewind the stream....

Feels really jerky, but that's the "best" solution I have for now.

I'm still open to suggestions.